# Realm not work SIGNAL SIGABRT with Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I use Xcode 9.2 with swift 4 for an IOS application 
everything work nice , but when i add realm [ save to DB after click on the button ] , and then click into the button the app crush with this message

```
SIGNAL SIGABRT
```

and when i changed the realm method with just a simple methode with

```
print("clicked")
```

it works

---

i use this pod line to add the library

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

and i have the code below

```
 floaty.addItem("Share", icon: UIImage(named: "share-variant")! , handler:{ item in
        self.shareTxt()
    })
    floaty.addItem("Save", icon: UIImage(named: "content-save")! , handler:{ item in
        self.saveToDB()
    })
```

---

```
func saveToDB() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.create(News.self, value: [SingleItem?.id])
    try! realm.commitWrite()

}
```

---

```
class News: Object {
@objc dynamic var new_id = ""
}
```

Comment: You should set up an exception breakpoint in debugger to catch the actual error, then edit your question to include that.

Comment: i can't find a way to catch the error ? i think it's inside realm library !

Answer (score 0):

First, make the property `new_id` as the Primary key:

```
class News: Object {
    @objc dynamic var new_id = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "new_id"
    }
}
```

Then, add or update the model:

```
func saveToDB() {
    if let newId = SingleItem?.id {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let news = realm.objects(News.self).filter("new_id == \(newId)").first

        if news != nil {
           try! realm.write {
               //optional, updating some fields...
               //like: news.title = "some title"
           }
        }
        else{
           let news = News(value: ["new_id", newId])
           try! realm.write {
               realm.add(news)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still have the error 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Like, no other message beyond that? :O